# validate presence and uniqueness, rails 4

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this code in my model:

```
  validates :user, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :project}
```

The individidual validators, presence and uniqueness, each work fine if the other one isn't there. But if they are both present as above, the presense validator stops working. When I try to save an object that has a nil user, instead of getting an normal save error, i get an exception:

NoMethodError: undefined method 'attributes' for nil:NilClass from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb:56:in `build_relation'

Is this a bug in ActiveRecord or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution (https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/459), but I don't think this is the best/right way. Just add `allow_nil: true`.

Then it should be like:

`validates :user, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :project}, allow_nil: true`